# Autocomplete failing when using Jupyter Notebook in a virtual environment

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter-lab

### The issue:

The autocomplete with the tab key is working with the default kernel but **not with the kernel created for my virtual env**.

Is there an additional procedure to make it work ?

### setup

```sh
pip install jupyterlab
mkdir project
cd project
pipenv install ipykernel
pipenv shell
python -m ipykernel install --user --name=`basename $VIRTUAL_ENV`
jupyter notebook
```

After that procedure I have a good setup:

- notebook are launching
- python is run from the virtual env as expected
- my new kernel is proposed when creating a notebook
- Packages installed on the virtual env are imported correctly

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading jedi does the trick : `pipenv install jedi==0.17.2`

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/12740